# manual_seed for mps devices in pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, gpu, apple-m1

How do I set up a manual seed for mps devices using pytorch?
With cuda devices the code should work like this:

```
if torch.cuda.is_available():
  torch.cuda.manual_seed(0)
```

I'm using an apple m1 chip. The following statement returns True:

```
torch.backends.mps.is_available()
```

But following statement is not possible:

```
torch.backends.mps.manual_seed(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html):

> You can use torch.manual_seed() to seed the RNG for all devices (both CPU and CUDA):

```
import torch
torch.manual_seed(0)
```

Comment: Does `torch.manual_seed(0)` really do the same as `torch.cuda.manual_seed(0)`? If no, what is the difference, or rather: why can it be used either way?

Comment: They are quite similar except `torch.cuda.manual_seed(0)` sets the seed for cuda **only** and `torch.manual_seed(0)` sets it on all devices.

Comment: Is there a way of setting the seed for a specific device (which is not `cuda`) only?

Comment: Currently (as MPS support is quite new) there is no way to set the seed for MPS directly. You can also use `torch.manual_seed(0)` for setting the seed for the CPU or if you are basing your calculations on random NumPy objects you can use `np.random.seed(0)`

Comment: just to clarify (in case the checkmark confuses anyone else), this does not in fact lead to the desired behavior, as can be checked with
`torch.manual_seed(0); torch.rand(5, device="mps")` compared against `torch.manual_seed(0); torch.rand(5, device="cpu")`
Is there any expectation that this will change?

Answer (score 1):

With PyTorch 2, Now you can set manual seed only to mps

```
import torch
torch.mps.manual_seed(0)
```

Here is the link to [Documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.mps.manual_seed.html#torch.mps.manual_seed)